# is ng-repeat causing infinite loop here? Angular/Node/Mongoose

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in projects">
<td>{{x.projects.project_name}}</td>
<td ng-hide="checkPermissions(x)"><button ng-click="deleteProject(x)"> Delete</button</td>
</tr>
```

the fuction checkPermissions will send an api with http.post to verify if the current user has the permission to delete the project
if he has no permission it will return false and the delete button won't be displayed
can you tell me why am i gettting an infinite loop?
i tested my api with Postman and it works like charm 
Console main error : $rootscope:infdig

Comment: Post the checkPermissions function, at the very east. Actually, just post the controller, probably.

Comment: the controller is the main controller of the body tag of the html page

Comment: thefunction is a simple http post that works fine with postman so the problem is with angularjs not the node

Comment: Then no one can help you based on those 4 lines.

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: what are the general cause of infinite loop in angular  i'm still a newbie

Comment: yeah infinite errors $rootscope:infdig

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not an infinite loop: `checkPermissions` is called on each view loop (equivalent to the framerate in angular). This is due to ng-hide which is called on every frame. The solution is to call `checkPermissions` only one time for each project in your controller and check only the result.

Like

```
// myController.js
$scope.projects.forEach(project => {
  project.canDisplay = checkPermissions(project)
}

// myHtml.html
ng-hide="x.canDisplay"
```

Comment: i'm calling it everytime because i have an array of projects and in front of each project name i have a delete button so every X will be verified in every call !! u understand me?

Comment: I understand what are you trying to do but I explain why `ng-hide` expression is called everytime. So, it's not youre code the infinite, it's the core of angularjs who worked like this. there is multiple solution to avoid a call of `checkPermissions` everytime, I suggested you one. Now, it seem you WANT to call checlPermissions everytime, and it's exactly what it does.

Comment: i didnt understand your solutions !! where should i place the checkPermissions function

Comment: Ho ok, it's edited. This is more comprehensive ?

Comment: Thanks , i just called my api before using the function then used the result in checkPermissions() !!

Answer (score 0):

Could you edit your question and show us the code in your angular controller? In general you might want to look into the angular documentation on infinite loop errors.

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig

**Good Luck!**